# CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) phpMyadmin install error

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, centos

I am trying to install phpAdmin on a Centos LAMP server and keep getting stuck at the same point which is a repository error. I am noob at linux and don't see what I am missing. I have been using the following walk through from [liquidweb](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-centos-7/)

Here is the error message I am receiving.

"[vadmin@centos-django ~]$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
[vadmin@centos-django ~]$ sudo rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
[sudo] password for vadmin: 
Retrieving http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.JKxeOc: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 352c64e5: NOKEY
Preparing...                                                    ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:epel-release-7-11                                          ################################# [ 50%]
Cleaning up / removing...
   2:epel-release-7-9                                           ################################# [100%]
[vadmin@centos-django ~]$ yum -y update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
You need to be root to perform this command.
[vadmin@centos-django ~]$ sudo yum -y update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
base                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
        yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again"

Comment: You shouldn't install packages with **rpm**. Please use `yum`.  Your errors → Suggest : Reinstall `epel-release` ...... → `# yum reinstall https://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm`

Comment: I reinstalled the vm and got this far with the same issue. this time i did not install the rpm as recommended.